# Can't delete mysql database, table or even alter table inside docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to have a mysql database with some basic dataset.
I create mysql docker image using this https://index.docker.io/u/brice/mysql/ Dockerfile, but delete `VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql", "/var/log/mysql"]` line, so the Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:12.10
MAINTAINER Brandon Rice <brice84@gmail.com>
RUN dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
RUN ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get -y install mysql-server
RUN sed -i -e"s/^bind-address\s*=\s*127.0.0.1/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/" /etc/mysql/my.cnf
RUN /usr/bin/mysqld_safe & \
    sleep 10s && \
    mysql < create_my_db.sql && \
    mysql -e "GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'root'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES" 

EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["mysqld_safe"]
```

After that I build image such as:

```
docker build -t my_db_mysql .
```

Everything is ok while i append data, but when i want to delete db, for example:

```
FROM my_db_mysql
RUN /usr/bin/mysqld_safe & \
    sleep 10s && \
    mysql -e "DROP DATABASE my_db;" 
EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["mysqld_safe"]
```

I obtain next error:

```
ERROR 6 (HY000) at line 1: Error on delete of './my_db//db.opt' (Errcode: 1)
```

It is appears not only when I want to build image, but even when I exec: `mysql -u user -p -e "DROP DATABASE my_db;"`
How to solve this?
Thanks

Update: Also I tried to run docker with different filesystem, e.g -s vfs or -s devicemapper, but nothing changed.
When I build image with `VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql", "/var/log/mysql"]` - everything works properly, but i can't commit this changes.
Update: Seems I resolve this issue. Problem was in host machine with ubuntu 12.04. Issue disappeared when I update ubuntu to 13.10. Thank a lot!

Comment: Can you indicate if you can successfully SELECT from this database? Does it appear with `SHOW DATABASES`? What's the content of `/var/lib/mysql`?

Comment: @jpetazzo Can you indicate if you can successfully SELECT from this database? - Yes. Does it appear with SHOW DATABASES? - SHOW DATABASES works properly.

Comment: Content of /var/lib/mysql: https://gist.github.com/rperegonchuk/8348957

Comment: Okay. Next step -- do you think you can provide a minimal `create_my_db.sql` file, so that we can fully reproduce the problem locally? Thank you!